# How to retrieve a web page needing authentication in Emacs, can't get url.el to authenticate

Tags: http, authentication, url, emacs

I'm using the following code:

```
(defvar xyz-user-name "LOGIN")
(defvar xyz-password "PASS")
(defvar site "http://www.site.com/")
(defvar xyz-block-authorisation nil 
"Flag whether to block url.el's usual interactive authorisation procedure")
(defadvice url-http-handle-authentication (around xyz-fix)
(unless xyz-block-authorisation
  ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'url-http-handle-authentication)
(defun login-show-posts ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((xyz-block-authorisation t)
         (url-request-method "GET")
         (url-request-extra-headers 
                      `(("Authorization" . ,(concat "Basic "
                                (base64-encode-string
                                 (concat xyz-user-name ":" xyz-password)))))))
     (url-retrieve site 
                   (lambda (status)
                   (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
```

But I just get the webpage text without authentication, i.e. it didn't authenticate. How can I make it authenticate. I've been busting my brains, reading everything on url-request-extra-headers that I could find, but can't get it done.

Anyone?

### Thanks

JJ

Comment: This looks fine to me.  a) Are you sure it doesn't send send the authorisation (the server might either not understand Basic auth or not accept it at that page, expecting a cookie set via a login page instead)  b) what version or url.el are you using? (I have heard of users having problems with my auth code with older versions of url.el) -- Have you tried a simple curl fetch to see if things work as you expect?

Comment: That might be it, I'm writing emacs code to enable monitoring of web pages. I have it working for non-auth webpages, and want to add in the functionality for auth webpages. Mostly for forums, i.e. you could use it to monitor for pages that have changed, but for that you need to download the authed page.

Could be the forum I tried uses cookies for auth, though it has a login and pass box atop each page.
Two questions then: how do I figure out if it supports auth? Is there a way to make url.el work using a preset cookie? I'm using the latest bzr checkout of Emacs, so url.el should be the latest

Comment: I thought url.el does cookie handling for you.  I.e. do the correct login-page dance to get cookies then retrieve the actual page you are interested in.   Regarding supported auth methods:  I suggest you try to get the page you intend with curl or wget (add suitable verbosity flags to see what gets sent, redirected etc.).  If that works you should be able to mirror that with the elisp code.

Comment: With the login-page dance you mean: if the login method would be via cookies, everytime I'd wish to retrieve the page via url.el, then have the code first enter the login details in the login page, and then in the next step retrieve the desired page? How is the cookie saved for successive lisp code steps, i.e. after doing a POST via url.el to enter the login data, where is the cookie saved so that url.el uses if for next steps in the code, when requesting the page?